# My image is set to position absolute, but when it goes off the screen, no scrollbar appears

Tags: javascript, html, css

My image will not create a scrollbar when it moves off-screen. It is set to absolute, but if the pixel coordinates exceed the screen-size, a scrollbar doesn't appear. It appeared in the other games I have made in the past, but it is not working now and I don't know why.

I have done research on what could be the problem, but I cannot figure it out. I tried setting the overflow to auto on the body and the image, but it makes not difference.

```
function sprite(picture){
this.sprite=document.createElement('img')
sps.push(this)
document.body.appendChild(this.sprite)
this.sprite.src="./images/"+picture
this.sprite.style.position="absolute"
this.sprite.overflow="auto"
//VARS
this.airborn=true
this.canJump=true
this.width=100
this.height=100
this.midX=window.innerWidth/2
this.midY=window.innerHeight/2
this.left=this.midX-this.width/2
this.top=this.midY-this.height/2
this.right=this.midX+this.width/2
this.bottom=this.midX+this.height/2
this.speedX=0
this.speedY=0
this.accelerationX=0
this.accelerationY=0
this.growthX=0
this.growthY=0
this.opacity=1
//FUNCTIONS
this.setX=function(value){
this.midX=value
this.left=this.midX-(this.width/2)
this.right=this.midX+(this.width/2)
this.sprite.style.left=this.left+"px"
}
this.setY=function(value){
this.midY=value
this.top=this.midY-(this.height/2)
this.bottom+=this.midY-(this.height/2)
this.sprite.style.top=this.top+"px"
}
this.setPos=function(x,y){
this.midX=x
this.left=this.midX-(this.width/2)
this.right=this.midX+(this.width/2)
this.sprite.style.left=this.left+"px"
this.midY=y
this.top=this.midY-(this.height/2)
this.bottom+=this.midY-(this.height/2)
this.sprite.style.top=this.top+"px"
}
this.setWidth=function(value){
this.width=value
this.left=this.midX-value/2
this.right=this.midX+value/2
this.sprite.width=this.width
}
this.setHeight=function(value){
this.height=value
this.top=this.midY-value/2
this.bottom=this.midY+value/2
this.sprite.height=this.height
}
this.setSize=function(w,h){
this.width=w
this.left=this.midX-w/2
this.right=this.midX+w/2
this.sprite.width=this.width
this.height=h
this.top=this.midY-h/2
this.bottom=this.midY+h/2
this.sprite.height=this.height
}
this.setOpacity=function(value){
this.opacity=0
this.sprite.style.opacity=value
}
this.crash=function(intSprite){
var crash=false
if(this.left<=intSprite.right&&this.right>=intSprite.left&&this.top<=intSprite.bottom&&this.bottom>=intSprite.top){crash=true}
return crash
}
}
```

I expect my sprite to create scroll bars as it moves off the screen, but instead, it just goes away.

Comment: Please clean up your indentation so the code is readable

Comment: Also please include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more information about it).

Comment: parent overflow is probably set to hidden

Comment: how do I fix the parent overflow?

Comment: sorry about the lack of formatting, I usually don't format my code while I do it.